# iOS SceneKit what is inversedTransform? (for dummies)

Tags: shader, scenekit, metal, ios14, cgaffinetransform

I'm new to the 3D rendering with `Metal` and `SceneKit`. I see that there is a specific "inverse" transform required to be passed to the renderer / shader. I printed out the transforms, and see no relationship between them. Google search results in a bunch of rather advanced topics.

So I ask a question for dummies, like myself:

**What is the meaning of "inverse" view transform for shaders?**

What happens if I don't inverse the transform?

```
// Apple code below (with original comment):
// Pass view-appropriate image transform to the shader modifier so
// that the mapped video lines up correctly with the background video.

let sceneView = renderer as? ARSCNView,
let frame = sceneView.session.currentFrame 

let affineTransform = frame.displayTransform(for: .portrait, viewportSize: self.view.bounds.size)
let transform = SCNMatrix4(affineTransform)
let inverse = SCNMatrix4Invert(transform) // pass to shader


transform: 
SCNMatrix4(
m11: 0.0, m12: 1.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0,
 m21: -1.5227804, m22: 0.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0,
 m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, 
m41: 1.2613902, m42: -0.0, m43: 0.0, m44: 1.0)
----
inversed:  
SCNMatrix4(
m11: 0.0, m12: -0.6566935, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, 
m21: 1.0, m22: 0.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0,
 m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, 
m41: 0.0, m42: 0.8283468, m43: 0.0, m44: 1.0)
```

Here's some info which suggests that the matrices above are a composite of translation, rotation and scaling. While CGAffine transform splits those into distinct elements, here they are all clamped together:

https://www.javatpoint.com/computer-graphics-3d-inverse-transformations

Comment: I'm not that good with my math talk, but basically, transform is a matrix that lets you go from one coordinate system to the other. It does that by changing a vector you are transforming from one set of basis vectors to another. And inverse transform does the opposite. If you have a transform that lets you go from a world coordinate system to view coordinate system (so that after multiplying any world vector becomes view vector), inverse does the opposite: view vectors back to world vectors. Matrix and transform are same in 3D cause all linear transforms can only be represented as a matrix.

Comment: Basically, this is comes down to linear algebra and affine transformations. There are articles and books that explain it much better, though I don't have concrete links.

Answer (score 0):

I found this excellent description of the steps that object coordinates go through before being passed into the renderer:

0. When rendering camera image, the inverse transform uses camera intrinsics to convert camera X,Y +optional depth into Object Space. Camera intrinsics converts 3D into 2D, so inversed transform goes from 2D to 3D

const auto localPoint = cameraIntrinsicsInversed * simd_float3(cameraPoint, 1) * depth;

1. Object (local) space to World space (localToWorld matrix in apple examples) (3x3 matrix)
2. World space to View/Eye/Camera space viewMatrix (3x3 matrix, Z axis pointing towards the viewer/camera, Y Axis pointing up)
3. View space to Clip Space using View Projection Matrix (4x4 matrix, has W component). **X,Y,Z greater than W will be clipped or culled- not rendered**. Created using `matrix_float4x4_perspective` function

> We now have a sequence of matrices that will move us all the way from
> object space to clip space, which is the space that Metal expects the
> vertices returned by our vertex shader to be in. Multiplying all of
> these matrices together produces a model-viewprojection (MVP) matrix,
> which is what we will actually pass to our vertex shader so that each
> vertex can be multiplied by it on the GPU.

```
// pseudocode, missing some matrix padding for multiplication purposes:
modelViewProjection = vertXYZ * localToWorld * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix
```

Renderer performs further transformations:

4. Clip Space to NDC (Normalized Device Coordinates) (half cube x,y -1 to 1, z 0 to 1)
5. NDC to Window Pixel positions

Answer (score 0):

When a SCNScene is captured by a camera, scene depth data is lost – that's because 3D objects are mapped onto a 2D image plane. However, if we want to do the reverse transformation, then it'll not work for reconstructing the 3D scene taking into account only the 2D image. We also need a depth. That's what `inversedTransform` is for.